# Visual bug in all my XML files (Android Studio)

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

When I try put the cursor on some character in a XML file, the character in the left of the cursor is displayed in double at the right of the cursor, like a big visual bug.

It's the same in all my others Android Studio projects. Why ?

EDIT: 
**I found the problem, it's because I change the size of the character in the editor.
My solution was putting the original size.**

Comment: Are you using latest version of Android Studio?

Comment: Yes, I use the latest version of Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem : it's because I change the size of the character in the editor.

**My solution : putting the original size**.